# I keep getting this error (TypeError: string indices must be integers) I don't know why

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, signal-processing

I just started using python, so I do not have much experience in this. I am trying to test the HRV library or package made by python to process the Electrocardiogram signal for my senior project. I am using Pycharm as my IDE.   I am trying to run this code:

```
from hrv.utils import open_rri
from array import array
rri = open_rri('C:/Users/PC/Documents/Pycharm/hrv-0.1.1/tests/test_files/test_file_2.hrm')
rri
array('u'[1092.,  879.,  746., ...,  931.,  968.,  958.])
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PC/Documents/Pycharm/hrv-0.1.1/tests/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    array('u'[1092.,  879.,  746., ...,  931.,  968.,  958.])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

I would appreciate your help,

thanks.

Comment: What's with that `'u'`?

Comment: can you, please, tell what you are trying to do?  Please read [dive into python arrays](http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html).

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `'u'` from your array creation so it will look like:

```
from hrv.utils import open_rri
from array import array
rri = open_rri('C:/Users/PC/Documents/Pycharm/hrv-
0.1.1/tests/test_files/test_file_2.hrm')
rri
array([1092.,  879.,  746., ...,  931.,  968.,  958.])
```

The way that you have it currently written, `'u'` is treated as a string and anything inside of the [] is treated as an index that you would like to retrieve. Index values must be an int, but you are specifying float values, hence why you are getting the error. If you need each of the values to be a Unicode value you can put the number in a char() function.

```
array([char(1092), char(879), ......, char(958)])
```

If you have quite a few values then you could just loop through the list of values appending their char versions to a new list that then gets turned into an array.

Comment: the reason why i added 'u' is that it has to be unicode. so when it is removed, the following error appears:                                             
                                                                                                                      TypeError: array() argument 1 must be a unicode character, not list